# Setting Up CiviCRM Multisite on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I run 2 sites on a Wordpress multisite. One of the sites has CiviCRM installed, and I want to hook up the second site to be able to access the Civi db as well. The first site is our main organization's website and handles membership, events, etc. The second site is a dedicated to one of our large annual events.

I am hoping to be able to access the Civi database from the second site to display the events in CiviEvent and allow for event registrations from the second site. That way people who register for the site will be added to our main Civi user database, rather than keeping track of two separate databases on each website.

The instructions on setting up a multisite in Civi seem quite complicated, so I am wondering if it is worth it to use multisite... Is this something that multisite can do? Is it worth doing, or is it far too difficult for too little reward?

Comment: I think you're confusing WordPress multisite with CiviCRM multisite - they're not the same thing. Please read the docs for each carefully if you're going to try this route. I should also make you aware that if you use a subfolder WordPress multisite, then CiviCRM won't function on any site other than the main site. You may have better luck with a subdomain install, or with domain-mapping. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Christian! I do understand that they are different things. My WP Multisite is installed in folders, but I do use domain mapping to make sitea.com and siteb.com point to the respective sites. Are you saying that CiviCRM multisite will not work in this situation?

Comment: It should work with domain mapping. It would be great if you can report back, or update the wiki with any findings.

Comment: I am at an impass, maybe you can help... I am following the directions on https://hq.palantetech.coop/projects/commons/wiki/CiviCRM_multi-site_checklist and http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Multi+Site+Installation . On the wiki, step 3 (3. Build navigation links for new domain/site) is completely confusing to me. I don't understand where to put this, or what it means by "import the file to your civicrm database." In addition, after doing step 5.C. WordPress multi-sites, my page displays  "you need to configure site : mysite.com" at the top. How do I do this??

Comment: I realise this post is from a few years ago. But I am currently having massive problems getting CiviCRM to acknowledge a multisite install. This is with CiviCRM 5.3 I was hoping that someone in this thread might have some insights. (I did have it working great in 4.7, but now it's just not working.) I started another thread here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25688/im-having-new-trouble-with-civicrm-in-multisites-in-wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be vastly superior to run multisite for the very fact you state: "That way people who register for the site will be added to our main Civi user database, rather than keeping track of two separate databases on each website."

One of the main benefits of using a CRM is to have a centralized database of all constituent information, be it contacts, contributions, events, etc. If you split it up, you are only causing yourself headaches later on trying to merge it.

Getting multisite working is worth it.  (Note: I haven't an idea how well Wordpress does multisite; my experience is usign Drupal.)

Comment: Thanks. The instructions for setting it up are so vague and sound really tricky... I'm glad to know its worth it before I try to figure out exactly what I have to do to get this to work.