# I'm having new trouble with CiviCRM in multisites in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

tldr; I'm after a Wordpress multisite setup that uses the same CiviCRM data for all the subsites. Each subsite can then show the relevant data, and users for each subsite can be given the appropriate permissions.

I've had this working previously, but now, using CiviCRM 5.2.2 it's refusing to work.

---

Previously (around Civi 4.6 ish) I did a multisite install of Civi.

All I did (IIRC) was install to the root site, then set it up.

When I went to the sub-sites, it showed me the CiviCRM information in the same way that it had it on the root site.

Everything was installed and working. I could see people and information about them.

I've just been trying to set up the same thing again, but this time I'm using CiviCRM 5.2.2

Now I successfully install CiviCRM in the main site.

But when I go to the sub sites, it has CiviCRM showing as needing installing. And when I try clicking the button it gives an error of:

Oops! CiviCRM is already installed
CiviCRM has already been installed.
To start over, you must delete or rename the existing CiviCRM settings file - civicrm.settings.php - from /wp-content/plugins/civicrm.

---

But civicrm.settings.php does not exist there.

It exists in /wp-content/uploads/civicrm

So the error message appears to be wrong as a first problem.

In the previous install that did work, it created a set of directories in:

/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/civicrm

And the civicrm.settings.php file was in there.

It has not done that in this case.

I'm very confused about what's going on.

Is this a major change between 4.x and 5.x that hasn't been documented?

Or something?

---

Things I've done
I've deleted the civicrm installation canary table from the the database.

I've added the lines to the civicrm settings file as per: 
https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/multi-site/

But it still refuses to let me get into CiviCRM on the subsites.

Thanks for any insight.

Norman

Answer (score 1):

I see you've commented on the [recent documentation update](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-sysadmin-guide/pull/104) to handle this, but in short: Newer versions of CiviCRM under WordPress have [moved the default location](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/18034/12) of `civicrm.settings.php`.  When installing multi-site, it's looking in the wrong location.  You can either define your `CIVICRM_SETTINGS_PATH` in `wp-config.php` or put the `civicrm.settings.php` in its old location.

Comment: Yes, another person pointed me as updated docs. Which certainly helped. 

But it hasn't solved the problems completely. I'm adding a post below.

Comment: So does CiviCRM no longer create sub sections in the /uploads/sites/--Site number--/ folders? Because no matter what i do, those folders are not created as they were before.

Comment: There is has raised another problem where I'm getting the dreaded "Network Error" and in the Console I'm getting this: 

Access to Font at 'https://dev.domain.nz/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0' from origin 'https://crew.dev.domain.nz' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://crew.dev.domain.nz' is therefore not allowed access.

=====

Comment: I have added 

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

to my .htaccess file, but that hasn't fixed it